# Better LINQ query to set value of property based on condition

Tags: c#, performance, linq

I have below LINQ,

```
Class class1
{
   public int Code {get; set;}
   public bool IsEditable {get; set;}
}

Class class2
{
   public string value {get; set;}
}

var list1 = LoadList(); // List<Class1>
var list2 = LoadList2();// List<Class2>

list1.Where(w => w.Code == 1).FirstOrDefault().IsEditable = List2.Where(w1 => w1.value == "one").Any();

list1.Where(w => w.Code == 2).FirstOrDefault().IsEditable = List2.Where(w1 => w1.value == "two").Any();
```

My linq grows as condition grows, is there a better way to replace multiple query to single query

Comment: Not sure what you are trying to do but `list1.FirstOrDefault(w => w.Code == 1).IsEditable = List2.Any(w1 => w1.value == "one");` Still you can get Null reference exception :)
`

Comment: Note that .FirstOrDefault can return null so you have the potential of a null ref exception there.

Comment: You need to explain what you're trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps something like this is what you are wanting to do? Where `dictionary` maps the values for you.

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace MyNamespace
{
    class Class1
    {
        public int Code { get; set; }
        public bool IsEditable { get; set; }
    }

    class Class2
    {
        public string Value { get; set; }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            var dictionary = new Dictionary<int, string>
            {
                {1, "one"}, 
                {2, "two"}
                // ...
            };

            var list1 = new List<Class1>();
            // add stuff to list 1
            var list2 = new List<Class2>();
            // add stuff to list 2

            foreach (var pair in dictionary)
            {
                list1.First(w => w.Code == pair.Key).IsEditable = list2.Any(w1 => w1.Value == pair.Value);
            }
        }
    }
}
```